# SimpleExpandableListAdapter issue in android application

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-listview, expandablelistadapter

I try to change a source code passing from android 2 to android 4.. The code doesn't gets me error and the application starts. But at the beginning there is a login. When i click on "Login" the app crashes. The logcat displays that there is a problem with `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`. this is the part of code that use the SimpleExpandableListAdapter:

```
expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(_ContactScreen_object,
                _groupSections, // groupData describes the first-level entries
                R.layout.group_row, // Layout for the first-level entries
                new String[] { "sectionName" }, // Key in the groupData maps to
                // display
                new int[] { R.id.groupname }, // Data under "friendName" key
                // goes into this TextView
                _result, // childData describes second-level entries
                R.layout.child_row, // Layout for second-level entries
                new String[] { "friendName", "status" }, // Keys in childData
                // maps to display
                new int[] { R.id.childname, R.id.rgb } // Data under the keys
        // above go into these
        // TextViews
        )
```

logcat:

[image]

Do you think that the problem is the code is old? The structure of `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` is different now? What have i to change?

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` param `_ContactScreen_object` is `null`. Here's line 210 of `SimpleExpandableListAdapter.java`:

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

More context (sic) of your code needed to provide further help.

Comment: If you can resolve the `null` context yourself, I don't need additional code. Otherwise include code showing what `_ContactScreen_object` is and how it is initialized.

Comment: Do you mean This? `public static ContactScreen _ContactScreen_object = null;`

Comment: Yes and here it's explicitly initialized to `null`. You need to pass the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` constructor a valid, non-null `Context` object, such as a reference to your `Activity`.

Comment: But do you think the problem is inside the part of code i posted?

Comment: but, in line 95 there is `import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;` and gets me an error